# I suddenly can’t “save as tiff” in image j, it said the image was locked but I ran a reset command to unlock it and it still doesn’t save

Tags: javascript, imagej

I’ve been using image j to count cells and I have been able to save hundreds of tiffs just fine by clicking file and save as tiff. All of a sudden I can’t do that. It says the image is locked or sometimes it says “nullnull” I have no idea what to do. Also I’m not an experienced coder at all. I just figured out macro was a thing today. But I have coded a little in R (not that that’s helpful here)

I’ve tried to Save as tiff multiple times. I also tried to save in other formats to see if it was only tiff but nothing else saved either. It gives a pixel per second thing and then just disappears like I never clicked any button. I also tried the save as command and it didn’t work for me either. If there is a JavaScript code I can put in macro I’d be happy to try anything at this point.

Comment: Is it possible that you have the file opened in an external image viewer or some other application that has opened the file in a way that denies write access and then your program is failing to write to the file (save the file) because the other app has not opened the file in a way that would permit writing by other apps (i.e. your app)? (e.g. in Windows, did not open it with FILE_SHARE_WRITE -- not sure what your OS is)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.